# Is there a tool to allow me to check out multiple git branches to the same worktree?

Tags: git

I vividly remember watching a video demo of a tool someone was working on about 2-3 years ago that would allow you to specify multiple branches you wanted to pull changes from into your current worktree, and it would help you manage which changes were from which branch, as well as which branch each new change should be committed back into.

For instance, if there's a branch that makes helpful updates to the dev environment, but it's not merged into main yet, I could check that out along with my feature branch, temporarily, just to make development easier, and then commit only my feature changes to my feature branch.

I have searched all over for this, and I know about `git-worktree`, which allows you to checkout two separate branches to two separate worktrees, but I can't find the tool I saw demoed anywhere... I vaguely recall that it may have been someone who previously did significant work on git... or maybe GitHub...

Does it exist?  DID it exist?  Am I from another dimension where it existed once??

Comment: Are you thinking of "git butler"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are thinking about [Git Butler](https://gitbutler.com/). The co-founder is Scott Chacon, co-founder of GitHub.

Comment: OH my goodness, THANK YOU so much!  Yes.  That is it.  (Why could I not find that??) 